# move_uploaded_file is failing

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I keep getting this error when trying to move an uploaded file to a directory on my server.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phposlycV' to '/home/star/mywebsite.org/view/PDFs/Elections/65.PDF'

Here is my code.

```
if ($_FILES['ufile']['type'] == "application/pdf") {
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO `my_candidates` (`Type`, `ElecName`, `ExpDate`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `State`, `Bio`) VALUES ('$Type', '$ElecName', '$ExpDate', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$State', '$Bio')");
    $sql2 = "SELECT max( ID ) AS `ID` FROM `my_candidates` WHERE `Type` = '$Type' AND `ElecName` = '$ElecName' AND `FirstName` = '$FirstName' AND `LastName` = '$LastName'";
    $newFileNameID = implode(' ', $db->query($sql2));
    $new_file_name=$newFileNameID.$Ext;
    rename($_FILES['ufile']["tmp_name"], $new_file_name);
    $tempDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PDFs/Elections/";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $tempDir . $new_file_name)) {
        echo "Uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Not Uploaded";
}
```

My chmod for that directory is 720. I have been knocking my head against this for hours. Any pointers you guys could throw my way would be much appreciated. The funny thing though it does upload to my `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` directory with the error still.

Comment: both directory have permission ..check  max execution time ..max upload size

Comment: You should have chmod 755 for folders and 644 for files.

Comment: The php.ini file you are referring to zod?

Comment: I don't know why, but the $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] returns the path of a directory, not a temporary file

Comment: Have you checked $_FILES['ufile']['error'] - it might tell you what's wrong http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: It gives me a value of 0 for that key. Thanks for the page though :) Informative. It is uploading to a directory, just not the "right" directory.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 720` will give read, write and execute permissions to the owner, write permission to the group and no permission at all for other.

If apache is not the owner of the directory, this is probably why it is not working.

Who is the current owner of the directory ? Did you try changing it with `chown` ?

Comment: Are you referring to me changing the permissions? I have tried 720, 755, and even 777.

Comment: I said changing the owner of the directory but, if you tried changing permissions to 777 and it is still not working, I doubt changing the owner will fix your issue.

Comment: I just don't understand how I could pass it a directory and it only puts it in the document root, says its failed. This one is confusing me.